# Sum in a mixed list of data

Tags: python, arrays, list, append

This is an specific questions that will help me finalize an outgoing project. It's pretty simple, I'm very new to Python and my background is mostly art. I like it, but I find it very challenging too.

I have a Text file (Data.txt) that contains a list of numbers/names, like this (short example):

```
String 1
34.6
45.6
45.9
String 2
34.6
45.6
45.9
```

This is a mixed list. After every String....12 numbers follow and so on. Notice that the numbers are 'float'.

I designed this:

```
numberList = []
data = []
data = open("SalesData.txt").read().split()
for i in data:
        numberList.append(i)
print numberList
```

This will append and print all the data in the external .txt list. How can I get all that data in the new list (numberList), but excluding all the 'Strings' found through the reading of the file. This way, I can perform a total Sum of only the numbers ---

Answer (score 2):

First, you shouldn't do `.read().split()` on your file - that will split on any whitespace, not just on newlines. Fortunately, Python can iterate directly over files.

Then, you could try to convert each line into a float and only append it to the list if that works (and skip it otherwise). Also, you can convert it to floats right away - makes summing it up easier.

```
number_list = []
with open("SalesData.txt") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        try:
            number_list.append(float(line))
        except ValueError:
            pass
print(sum(number_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

just iterate over the lines and only add the numbers to the list ...

```
with open("somefile.txt") as f:
     my_list = []
     for line in f:
         try:
            my_list.append(float(line))
         except ValueError:
             pass

print sum(my_list)
```

Comment: Yay, two people had the same (correct) idea at the same time. No need to strip whitespace, by the way.

Comment: actually this might be wrong in the particular case where the labels are numeric. Not sure if it is a possible case for the OP

Comment: @lcfseth: If the labels *were* numeric, how would you be able to tell that they were labels and not values?

Comment: well he said that the file has a predifined pattern: 1 label - 12 number, 1 label - 12 number ...

Answer (score 1):

If your data is structured (which seems to be the case), I would simply use a counter and drop the 1st element of each sequence of len 12.

Here's an example:

```
numberList = []
data = []
counter = 0
with open("SalesData.txt") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        if counter > 0:
            number_list.append(float(line))
        counter = (counter + 1) % 12
print numberList
```

Comment: This is great! But I think there is conflict with the first line :: it's a string, so it prompts me an error. Any way to go around it? Maybe initialize the counter to 1, so it starts in line 2? Let me know any suggestions.

Comment: This is my favorite approach if you can direct me correctly!!

Comment: yeah, I'll use the iteration presented on your solution. Together we should get the right answer :) Should work correctly now.

Comment: @mmmaceo: The counter initialization was correct. As pointed by Tim Pietzcker, the split function would add empty values to the set. That's what was causing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
tsum = []
for j in numberList:
    try: tsum.append(float(j))
    except: pass
sum = sum(tsum)
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but j is most likely an str or unicode in all cases since there is no parsing involved.

Answer (score 0):

You could do type checking, or if the numbers are actually digits in a string, you could do something like a `"13".isdigit()` check but I'd probably want to do something a little  more clever:

```
numberList = []

for i in range(0, len(data)/13):
    numberList.append(data[1*(i+1):13*(i+1)])
```

That (or something like it) should target the groups of numbers after the strings. This does depend on your input data not being junk, but it should work quicker on large datasets than doing `.isdigit()` or other type checks.

Comment: the .isdigit() would be perfect, but I don't think it works with Floats?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

ss =  '''String 1 
34.6 
45.6 
45.9 
String 2 
34.6 
45.6 
45.9 

'''

print re.findall('^(?!.*?[a-zA-Z])[0-9.+-]+',ss,re.MULTILINE)
```

But if there can be letters whose none is ASCII, it won't work

Comment: @mmmaceo The problem is simply the well known problem of determining if a string can be transformed in a float, combined with the necesity to iterate on the lines in a text. Concerning the problem of "floatifying" a string, there are quantaties of threads in stackoverflow